# What is the root of "El bokeh wall" naming?

Tags: terminology, bokeh

I've found that bokeh wall in some sources is referred as **El** Bokeh Wall. I wonder: why is that? Searching gives no answer. Is it in spanish or something else?
Example of using "El Bokeh Wall": http://www.diyphotography.net/el-bokeh-wall/

Comment: All the potential sources for the term 'el bokeh wall' I looked at seem to lead back to that same article.  Either way the etymology makes no sense since Bokeh roots in Japanese and El would be Spanish/Portuguese.

Comment: @JamesSnell I'm pretty sure that's all there is to the answer. Unless, Flame, you've seen this somewhere else?

Comment: @mattdm After additional research I can't find any other sources. It seems that it's only author of that article calls this technique that way. Alright, I can accept an answer if you post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer from Laya himself: "The el doesn't have any meaning. Haha. Just wanted to call it the el bokeh wall". Great mystery resolved :)

Answer (score 2):

Wild guess based on the fact that the the author is named *Laya*.

I wonder if "the El bokeh wall" -- which the author says is naming by himself

> I call it “The El Bokeh Wall”

-- simply stands for "the effect given by a background wall where bokeh plays a predominant role made by someone whose name begins with L".

Note that the author is based in the Philippines where spanish is not unheard of, so it could well be a play on words.

Comment: I also note that this is a wild guess and so maybe it doesn't deserve to be an answer. If you feel so, I will remove it.

Comment: It absolutely is an answer - I missed the part in the article where the author says they're naming it.

Answer (score 1):

I did some digging around on this and all the potential sources for the term 'el bokeh wall' appear to eventually lead back to that same article which suggests that the term was coined by the author.

Since Bokeh is Japanese and El would be Spanish/Portuguese, the etymology of those words doesn't lend support to the term being coined by a native speaker of either and there are previous examples of people using 'El' as an alternative for 'the old' as a reference to something familiar (as in to give them 'the old 1-2'.)

But... it's always worth dropping the author a line an seeing what they have to say.